# Binding more attributes in scoped slots

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a component with a scoped slot. In component I have:

```html
<div v-for="(row, i) in rows" :key="i + 0">
```

and inside this div I have two named scoped slots. In one of them I need to pass index as well.

In component

```html
<slot name="mySlot" v-bind="{item}, i"></slot>
```

In usage

```html
<template slot="mySlot" slot-scope="{item}, i" v-if="item.open">
```

But that doesn't work.

Is it possible to pass index somehow as well?

Comment: Isn't it just `{item, i}` in both places?

Comment: Yes it is... I missed the class about destructuring.